# Authorization using Web.config Vs Manual Authorization

Tags: asp.net

Once the user is authenticated, I fetch the `User information` from the Database and saves it in `Session`.

Now, In order to validate the user to authorize for a particular page, Enumeration is present for Roles/Pages. Finally I compares it with the Session data for indivisual page. As, directories can be nested, So, I personally feel that it is a flexible approach.

So, Is it a Good practice or I can use `FormAuthentication Ticket Class` as the approach use `Web.Config`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form Authentication provides you less effort to write basic security of your web pages.

offcourse you can write your own code as you mentioned , but you have to make sure that all the pages must have authentication checks either by writing code on all the pages or by deriving your authentication checks from a single base page or helper classes.

I myself never want to write custom code for authentication as FormAuthentication itself provides you protecting all the directory/pages inside your website.

There are many other features e.g.

```
1) You can choose which file/folder should not be secure
2) Get loggedin user details at any secure page
3) Default and Login url redirections 
4) Logout feature and redirecting to default/login page automatically
5) Role wise security , Role based page/folder access etc.
```

explore google for this and you'll find more advantages...